# Using variables to check if certain things are allowed

Tags: php, security, variables, upload, global

i was thinking of implementing features of turning on and off certain things on my website like registering and logging of.
I could include a file with variables like so

```
<?php
$upload = 1;
$register = 1;
?>
```

And then in suppose my register.php file i could do a check like so

```
if($register == 1){
//Show form
} else { echo "Registration is disabled" }
```

i was wondering if this would be a security issue as i read somewhere that stuff can be suffixed the url to bring the same effect
Like so

```
register.php?register=1
```

But that does not work if register globals are turned off, is this much of a security issue?

Comment: no, you understood it right; that is a issue only if you are using register globals (a feature that was deprecated and removed in 5.4)

Answer (score 2):

#### NO

`register.php?register=1` will only be accessed from `$_GET['register']`
<sub>Unless you're using an older version of PHP with register_globals turned on</sub> <sup>*Thanks Lex*</sup>

If you are configuring some features on the server, I suggest you use sessions instead.

```
$_SESSION['upload'] = 1;
$_SESSION['register'] = 1;
```

Unlike constants, they can be changed, if some criteria is met.

And [`register_globals()`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is removed from the latest PHP 5.4.0, so, dont use that.

Comment: Except if you're using an older version of PHP with register_globals turned on, which you shouldn't of course.

Comment: i use php 5.3 which has register_globals turned off by default, and thanks for the answer @Starx

Comment: aren't these set to null or something when session_destroy() is called?

Comment: @MarshallMathews, when session_destroy() is called, the session is completely wiped. Every variable is unset completely.

Answer (score 2):

You are somewhat better off using constants instead of variables if you are sourcing these from an included file. The constants cannot be modified at runtime, under any circumstance:

```
define('UPLOAD', 1);
define('REGISTER', 1);

if (defined('REGISTER') && REGISTER === 1) {
  // Registration disabled
}
```

As long as `register_globals` is turned off (which it should be!!!!), global variables cannot be modified via the HTTP request in `$_GET,$_POST,$_REQUEST` unless you explicitly do so in code by accessing those superglobals.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have register_globals off, you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

With register globals off, it's not a problem at all. The issue comes if you get input like this:

$register = $_GET['register'];

and don't check that you actually got a number instead of some malicious code.